# JavaScript - Issue with Rendering the guage component

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a Javascript to render a Speedometer guage in my application. From the existing script, the range values are from 0-80 and I'm trying to change the range values of the speedometer -say 0-240.

I'm able to change the text marker values, but I'm not able to make the needle to point the text marker value.

I want to achieve by making the pointer to locate exact text marker value.

In the `drawTextMarker()` method, I've changed the following code to change my text values in marker.

```
iTickToPrint += 30;
```

Please find below my code.

```js
/*jslint plusplus: true, sloppy: true, indent: 4 */
(function () {
    "use strict";
    // this function is strict...
}());

var iCurrentSpeed = 20,
    iTargetSpeed = 20,
    bDecrement = null,
    job = null;

function degToRad(angle) {
    // Degrees to radians
    return ((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
}

function radToDeg(angle) {
    // Radians to degree
    return ((angle * 180) / Math.PI);
}

function drawLine(options, line) {
    // Draw a line using the line object passed in
    options.ctx.beginPath();

    // Set attributes of open
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = line.alpha;
    options.ctx.lineWidth = line.lineWidth;
    options.ctx.fillStyle = line.fillStyle;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = line.fillStyle;
    options.ctx.moveTo(line.from.X, line.from.Y);

    // Plot the line
    options.ctx.lineTo(
        line.to.X,
        line.to.Y
    );

    options.ctx.stroke();
}

function createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, fillStyle, lineWidth, alpha) {
    // Create a line object using Javascript object notation
    return {
        from: {
            X: fromX,
            Y: fromY
        },
        to:    {
            X: toX,
            Y: toY
        },
        fillStyle: fillStyle,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        alpha: alpha
    };
}

function drawOuterMetallicArc(options) {
    /* Draw the metallic border of the speedometer 
     * Outer grey area
     */
    options.ctx.beginPath();

    // Nice shade of grey
    //options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(127,127,127)";
    //options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    
    var my_gradient = options.ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,20,145);
    my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"purple");
    my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"pink");
    options.ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;

    // Draw the outer circle
    options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
        options.center.Y,
        options.radius-10,
        0,
        Math.PI,
        true);

    // Fill the last object
    options.ctx.fill();
}

function drawInnerMetallicArc(options) {
    /* Draw the metallic border of the speedometer 
     * Inner white area
     */

    options.ctx.beginPath();

    // White
    options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    
    //var my_gradient = options.ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,15,135);
    //my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"purple");
    //my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"brown");
     //options.ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;

    // Outer circle (subtle edge in the grey)
    options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
                    options.center.Y,
                    options.radius-10,
                    0,
                    Math.PI);

    options.ctx.fill();
}

function drawMetallicArc(options) {
    /* Draw the metallic border of the speedometer
     * by drawing two semi-circles, one over lapping
     * the other with a bot of alpha transparency
     */

    drawOuterMetallicArc(options);
    drawInnerMetallicArc(options);
}

function drawBackground(options) {
    /* Black background with alphs transparency to
     * blend the edges of the metallic edge and
     * black background
     */
    var i = 0;

    options.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    //var my_gradient = options.ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,30,220);
    //my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"white");
    //my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"aqua");
    //options.ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
    options.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";

    // Draw semi-transparent circles
    for (i = 140; i < 150; i++) {
        options.ctx.beginPath();

        options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
            options.center.Y,
            i,
            0,
            Math.PI,
            true);

        options.ctx.fill();
    }
}

function applyDefaultContextSettings(options) {
    /* Helper function to revert to gauges
     * default settings
     */

    options.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    options.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
}

function drawSmallTickMarks(options) {
    /* The small tick marks against the coloured
     * arc drawn every 5 mph from 10 degrees to
     * 170 degrees.
     */

    var tickvalue = options.levelRadius - 8,
        iTick = 0,
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        iTickRad = 0,
        onArchX,
        onArchY,
        innerTickX,
        innerTickY,
        fromX,
        fromY,
        line,
        toX,
        toY;

    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);

    // Tick every 20 degrees (small ticks)
    for (iTick = 10; iTick < 180; iTick += 20) {
        iTickRad = degToRad(iTick);

        /* Calculate the X and Y of both ends of the
         * line I need to draw at angle represented at Tick.
         * The aim is to draw the a line starting on the 
         * coloured arc and continueing towards the outer edge
         * in the direction from the center of the gauge. 
         */

        onArchX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iTickRad) * tickvalue);
        onArchY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iTickRad) * tickvalue);
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iTickRad) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iTickRad) * gaugeOptions.radius);

        fromX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + onArchX;
        fromY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + onArchY;
        toX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickX;
        toY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickY;

        // Create a line expressed in JSON
        line = createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, "rgb(127,127,127)", 3, 0.6);

        // Draw the line
        drawLine(options, line);
    }
}

function drawLargeTickMarks(options) {
    /* The large tick marks against the coloured
     * arc drawn every 10 mph from 10 degrees to
     * 170 degrees.
     */

    var tickvalue = options.levelRadius - 8,
        iTick = 0,
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        iTickRad = 0,
        innerTickY,
        innerTickX,
        onArchX,
        onArchY,
        fromX,
        fromY,
        toX,
        toY,
        line;

    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);

    tickvalue = options.levelRadius - 2;

    // 10 units (major ticks)
    for (iTick = 20; iTick < 180; iTick += 20) {

        iTickRad = degToRad(iTick);

        /* Calculate the X and Y of both ends of the
         * line I need to draw at angle represented at Tick.
         * The aim is to draw the a line starting on the 
         * coloured arc and continueing towards the outer edge
         * in the direction from the center of the gauge. 
         */

        onArchX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iTickRad) * tickvalue);
        onArchY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iTickRad) * tickvalue);
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iTickRad) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iTickRad) * gaugeOptions.radius);

        fromX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + onArchX;
        fromY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + onArchY;
        toX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickX;
        toY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickY;

        // Create a line expressed in JSON
        line = createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, "rgb(127,127,127)", 3, 0.6);

        // Draw the line
        drawLine(options, line);
    }
}

function drawTicks(options) {
    /* Two tick in the coloured arc!
     * Small ticks every 5
     * Large ticks every 10
     */
    drawSmallTickMarks(options);
    drawLargeTickMarks(options);
}

function drawTextMarkers(options) {
    /* The text labels marks above the coloured
     * arc drawn every 10 mph from 10 degrees to
     * 170 degrees.
     */
    var innerTickX = 0,
        innerTickY = 0,
        iTick = 0,
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        iTickToPrint = 0;

    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);

    // Font styling
    options.ctx.font = 'italic 10px sans-serif';
    options.ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
     
    options.ctx.beginPath();

    // Tick every 20 (small ticks)
    for (iTick = 10; iTick < 180; iTick += 20) {
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(degToRad(iTick)) * gaugeOptions.radius);
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(degToRad(iTick)) * gaugeOptions.radius);

        // Some cludging to center the values (TODO: Improve)
        if (iTick <= 10) {
            options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX,
                    (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY + 5);
        } else if (iTick < 50) {
            options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX - 5,
                    (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY + 5);
        } else if (iTick < 90) {
            options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX,
                    (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY);
        } else if (iTick === 90) {
            options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX + 4,
                    (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY);
        } else if (iTick < 145) {
            options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX + 10,
                    (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY);
        } else {
            options.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
            options.ctx.fillText(iTickToPrint, (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickX + 15,
                    (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius - 12) + innerTickY + 5);
        }

        // MPH increase by 10 every 20 degrees
        // iTickToPrint += Math.round(2160 / 9);
        iTickToPrint += 30;
    }

    options.ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSpeedometerPart(options, alphaValue, strokeStyle, startPos) {
    /* Draw part of the arc that represents
    * the colour speedometer arc
    */
    options.ctx.beginPath();

    options.ctx.globalAlpha = alphaValue;
    options.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;

    options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
        options.center.Y,
        options.levelRadius,
        Math.PI + (Math.PI / 360 * startPos),
        0 - (Math.PI / 360 * 10),
        false);

    options.ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSpeedometerColourArc(options) {
    /* Draws the colour arc.  Three different colours
     * used here; thus, same arc drawn 3 times with
     * different colours.
     * TODO: Gradient possible?
     */

    var startOfGreen = 10,
        endOfGreen = 280,
        endOfOrange = 280;

    drawSpeedometerPart(options, 1.0, "rgb(82, 240, 55)", startOfGreen);
    // drawSpeedometerPart(options, 0.9, "rgb(198, 111, 0)", endOfOrange);
    drawSpeedometerPart(options, 0.9, "rgb(255, 0, 0)", endOfGreen);
}

function drawNeedleDial(options, alphaValue, strokeStyle, fillStyle) {
    /* Draws the metallic dial that covers the base of the
    * needle.
    */
    var i = 0;

    options.ctx.globalAlpha = alphaValue;
    options.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    options.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    options.ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;

    // Draw several transparent circles with alpha
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        options.ctx.beginPath();
        options.ctx.arc(options.center.X,
            options.center.Y,
            i,
            0,
            Math.PI,
            true);

        options.ctx.fill();
        options.ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function convertSpeedToAngle(options) {
    /* Helper function to convert a speed to the 
    * equivelant angle.
    */
     
    var iSpeed = (options.speed / 10),
        iSpeedAsAngle = ((iSpeed * 20) + 10) % 180;

    // Ensure the angle is within range
    if (iSpeedAsAngle < 0) {
        iSpeedAsAngle = iSpeedAsAngle + 180;
    }else if(iSpeedAsAngle > 180) {
        iSpeedAsAngle = iSpeedAsAngle - 180;
    }
    
    return iSpeedAsAngle;
}

function drawNeedle(options) {
    /* Draw the needle in a nice read colour at the
    * angle that represents the options.speed value.
    */

    var iSpeedAsAngle = convertSpeedToAngle(options),
        iSpeedAsAngleRad = degToRad(iSpeedAsAngle),
        gaugeOptions = options.gaugeOptions,
        innerTickX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * 20),
        innerTickY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * 20),
        fromX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickX,
        fromY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + innerTickY,
        endNeedleX = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.cos(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * gaugeOptions.radius),
        endNeedleY = gaugeOptions.radius - (Math.sin(iSpeedAsAngleRad) * gaugeOptions.radius),
        toX = (options.center.X - gaugeOptions.radius) + endNeedleX,
        toY = (gaugeOptions.center.Y - gaugeOptions.radius) + endNeedleY,
        line = createLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, "rgb(255,0,0)", 5, 0.6);

    drawLine(options, line);

    // Two circle to draw the dial at the base (give its a nice effect?)
    drawNeedleDial(options, 0.6, "rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(255,255,255)");
    drawNeedleDial(options, 0.2, "rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(127,127,127)");
}

function buildOptionsAsJSON(canvas, iSpeed) {
    /* Setting for the speedometer 
    * Alter these to modify its look and feel
    */
    var centerX = 170,
        centerY = 170,
        radius = 110,
        outerRadius = 175;

    // Create a speedometer object using Javascript object notation
    return {
        ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
        speed: iSpeed,
        center:    {
            X: centerX,
            Y: centerY
        },
        levelRadius: radius - 10,
        gaugeOptions: {
            center:    {
                X: centerX,
                Y: centerY
            },
            radius: radius
        },
        radius: outerRadius
    };
}

function clearCanvas(options) {
    options.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    applyDefaultContextSettings(options);
}

function draw() {
    /* Main entry point for drawing the speedometer
    * If canvas is not support alert the user.
    */
    console.log('Target: ' + iTargetSpeed);
    console.log('Current: ' + iCurrentSpeed);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial'),
        options = null;

    // Canvas good?
    if (canvas !== null && canvas.getContext) {
        options = buildOptionsAsJSON(canvas, iCurrentSpeed);

        // Clear canvas
        clearCanvas(options);

        // Draw the metallic styled edge
        drawMetallicArc(options);

        // Draw thw background
        drawBackground(options);

        // Draw tick marks
        drawTicks(options);

        // Draw labels on markers
        drawTextMarkers(options);

        // Draw speeometer colour arc
        drawSpeedometerColourArc(options);

        // Draw the needle and base
        drawNeedle(options);
    } else {
        alert("Canvas not supported by your browser!");
    }

    if(iTargetSpeed == iCurrentSpeed) {
        clearTimeout(job);
        return;
    } else if(iTargetSpeed < iCurrentSpeed) {
        bDecrement = true;
    } else if(iTargetSpeed > iCurrentSpeed) {
        bDecrement = false;
    }

    if(bDecrement) {
        if(iCurrentSpeed - 10 < iTargetSpeed)
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed - 1;
        else
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed - 5;
    } else {
        if(iCurrentSpeed + 10 > iTargetSpeed)
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed + 1;
        else
            iCurrentSpeed = iCurrentSpeed + 5;
    }

    job = setTimeout("draw()", 5);
}

function drawWithInputValue() {
    var txtSpeed = document.getElementById('txtSpeed');
     
    if (txtSpeed !== null) {
        iTargetSpeed = txtSpeed.value;

        // Sanity checks
        if (isNaN(iTargetSpeed)) {
            iTargetSpeed = 0;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed < 0) {
            iTargetSpeed = 0;
        } else if (iTargetSpeed > 80) {
            iTargetSpeed = 80;
        }

        job = setTimeout("draw()", 5);
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Speedometer HTML5 Canvas</title>
    <script src="speedometer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="380" height="170">Canvas not available.</canvas>
    <div>
        <form id="drawTemp">
            <input type="text" id="txtSpeed" name="txtSpeed"> </input>
            <input type="button" value="Draw" onClick="drawWithInputValue();">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
    window.onload = drawsRandomValues;
    function drawsRandomValues() {
        //var n = 25;
        // var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*n)+1;
        var number = randomIntFromInterval(0,220);
        document.getElementById("txtSpeed").innerHTML = number;
        document.getElementById("txtSpeed").value = number;
        //alert(number);
        drawWithInputValue();
    }
    setInterval("drawsRandomValues();", 3000);
</script>
</html>
```

Anyone please suggest me where I've to change the code to achieve this.

PS: I've found the above script from [Speedometer example](http://geeksretreat.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/making-a-speedometer-using-html5s-canvas/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be this part of `convertSpeedToAngle()`:

```
var iSpeed = (options.speed / 10),
    iSpeedAsAngle = ((iSpeed * 20) + 10) % 180;
```

If you put in 40, then you get (((40/10) * 20) + 10)%180 = 90 for the angle.  How the hell they came up with that thinking is beyond me.

Since you know that the range is 0-180 degrees, then you want to know the % of those degrees your current value uses and then find the related angle in degrees.

The % as a decimal in the range [0-1] is given by `options.speed / 240` since 240 is the max on your scale.

Take that percentage and multiply it by 180 to get where it should fall in terms of the degrees.  Then, the function quite simply becomes (without any error checking!):

```
function convertSpeedToAngle(options) {
  return 180 * options.speed/240;
}
```

Try plugging that in and see if your issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Miller for your idea. I tried your approach but the results were different at some angles.

By the way, i figured it out like changing the below code as from

```
var iSpeed = (options.speed / 10),
iSpeedAsAngle = ((iSpeed * 20) + 10) % 180;
```

to new code like below

```
var iSpeed = (options.speed / 30), // 30 --> between tick interval range  
iSpeedAsAngle = ((iSpeed * 20) + 10) ; // omitted the modulo operator of 180
```

Above change of code in `convertSpeedToAngle()` method, enables the needle to point the exact tick value.